# Time error wrong output

Tags: c++

```
    time_t ltime;
    time( &ltime );
    tm *    pTm = localtime(&ltime);

    printf("%d",pTm->tm_wday);
```

output= 2 , how come while 2day is 8 -.- anyclue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tm_wday` is the weekday, indexed from 0 being Sunday, to 6 being Saturday.

It is 2 today because it's a Tuesday.

What you want to access for the day of the month is `tm_mday`.

#### See also:

- [Members of `struct tm` explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h#Calendar_time)

Answer (score 2):

Because tm_wday is the day since Sunday. Therefore it is 2. What you want is tm_mday

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/